# How do I get the child process id in Parallel::ForkManager?

Tags: perl, parallel-processing, fork

```
  use LWP::Simple;
  use Parallel::ForkManager;


  @links=( 
    ["http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/sweethome3d/SweetHome3D-2.1-windows.exe","SweetHome3D-2.1-windows.exe"], 
    ["http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/sweethome3d/SweetHome3D-2.1-macosx.dmg","SweetHome3D-2.1-macosx.dmg"],
    ["http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/sweethome3d/SweetHome3DViewer-2.1.zip","SweetHome3DViewer-2.1.zip"],

  );

  # Max 30 processes for parallel download
  my $pm = new Parallel::ForkManager(30); 

  foreach my $linkarray (@links) {
    my $pid = $pm->start and next; # do the fork

    my ($link,$fn) = @$linkarray;
    warn "Cannot get $fn from $link"
      if getstore($link,$fn) != RC_OK;

    print "$pid = $link is done ";

    $pm->finish; # do the exit in the child process
  }
  $pm->wait_all_children;
```

after this execution i am going pid is zero

```
0 = http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/sweethome3d/SweetHome3DViewer-2.1.zip is done 

0 = http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/sweethome3d/SweetHome3D-2.1-macosx.dmg is done 

0 = http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/sweethome3d/SweetHome3D-2.1-windows.exe is done
```

But now I really thinking whether its really doing the fork. Why I am getting all times 0 as pid in Parallel::ForkManager?

***EDIT 2***

i have 2 changes

```
my $pid = $pm->start ; # do the fork
```

and `$$` for process id

```
21892 = http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/sweethome3d/SweetHome3D-2.1-windows.exe is done 

21893 = http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/sweethome3d/SweetHome3D-2.1-windows.exe is done 

21892 = http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/sweethome3d/SweetHome3D-2.1-macosx.dmg is done 

23120 = http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/sweethome3d/SweetHome3D-2.1-macosx.dmg is done 

21892 = http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/sweethome3d/SweetHome3DViewer-2.1.zip is done 

23146 = http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/sweethome3d/SweetHome3DViewer-2.1.zip is done
```

But now I am getting 2 twice. Why I am getting this?

Comment: Just a guess but perhaps Parallel:ForkManager is reusing the process since the download is complete?

Comment: Scrub that last comment, the $pm->finish should exit the child process.
But since you dropped the 'and next' from the start call the parent process is also running the download as well. I am guessing 21892 is the pid of the parent process which will run through the loop multiple times.

Comment: @nic String - Add this information into ur answer then i will accept your answer :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure about the Parallel::ForkManager implementation, but if it is anything like standard fork() the 0 is being returned because you are in the child process. Fork will only return a non-zero pid to the parent process.

I forgot to add, given the 'and next' after the start call the code is behaving exactly as expected.

Note to EDIT 2:

Since you dropped the 'and next' from the start call the parent process is also running the download as well. I am guessing 21892 is the pid of the parent process which will run through the loop multiple times

Answer (score 5):

About your code below Edit2:

You changed

```
my $pid = $pm->start and next;
```

to

```
my $pid = $pm->start ; # do the fork
```

Now you are not doing the fork correctly. While previously only the child continued executing the loop body and the parent taking the *next*, now both continue executing the loop body. Therefore you see the pid of the parent (21892) executing the loop several times.

Answer (score 4):

See that line?

```
my $pid = $pm->start and next; # do the fork
```

The parent gets the pid, the child will see only 0. If you want to get your pid from within the child process, simply use the magic variable `$$`.

UPDATE:

The reference to that line was not meant as a invitation to change the line. But looking at it, it should become obvious that $pid will be 0 in the code following the line so it should hardly come as a surprise that a `print $pid` would print `0` and nothing else.

Comment: @Manni - after this got 2 times running

Comment: 2 times running? Not sure what you are trying to say. sorry.

Comment: if you are seen the output of that process execution it shows its printing 2 times . but it should show one only times

Comment: Why did you change the $pm->start line??

Answer (score 0):

```
forloop{
if (my $pid = $pm->start($linkarray)){
              print "pid-i-got-from-child=$pid and this code is running under pid=$$\n";
              next;
            }
... and then continue with code processing in child process...

}
```

this will give you child pid and also continue to process code with fork.